# What can be scenarios of Blob cache suffering from sync and / or corruption issues

Tags: 2007, central-administration, cache

I was reading answer to this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21827/when-would-you-flush-the-cache-of-a-sharepoint-web-application)

I wonder what can be possible scenarios any type of Cache in sharepoint suffering from corruption issues.

**EDIT**

Please only mention your personal experiences, as I can do googling as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main causes past database corruption and these also generally cause database corruption also but there are also some rare causes:

1. Out of system memory
2. Not enough hard disk space
3. Application crash
4. Corrupt data in a stored field used in the cache

Causes of these are:

1. Insufficient hardware
2. poor provisioning of hardware resources
3. Memory leaks
4. Buffer overflow errors
5. Attempting to bypass encoding methods used to store data
6. Broken or missing database locks
7. Disk drives that do not honor sync requests
8. Disk drive / Flash Memory / Memory failure
9. A process sharing the database with another process and both attempt writes together
10. Anything similar to the above.

Other rare causes are generally to do with a poor database setup or database manipulation, for example changing the encoding of one database and not in another database, which in this scenario should never be attempted anyway.

Everything I have listed are all bad practices and that for a reason.